# iCal share multiple calendars with one person

Tags: icloud, calendar, ical, google-calendar

I'd like to share all my calendars with my boss. She shares her calendars with me using Google Calendar and I was hoping doing the same with my calendars.
How can I share multiple calendars to be visible as one? I can only find calendars to be shared one-by-one.

Comment: I've updated your question to be more specific and improved readability to improve the chances of getting the right answer.

Comment: Apple's ical only allows one-by-one sharing. I don't know of an app that does what you want